# Export time column to Excel in GeneXus

Tags: genexus

Is it possible to export a cell of the type `time`?

For example: `12:43:32`. What I get is `'12:43:32`, text format.

&ExcelDocument.Cells(&CellRow, &FirstColumn + &VisibleColumnCount).Text = SolfonAtendiHoras

`SolfonAtendiHoras` is `varchar(11)` with picture `ZZZ99:99:99`
The goal is to have this attribute as accumulated time an then calculate average, sum, etc in excel.

GX X EV3 U9 + WWP 10.1.18 (The export procedure is generated by WWP pattern)

Comment: How are you creating the Excel file? Can yo show some code? What GeneXus version?